# What's the appropriate way to document the versions of tools used in my project?

Tags: git, github, version-control

Suppose there's a project of mine that uses GNU bash version `5.0.17(1)-release`
and also uses Python `3.10.1`, with modules like numpy `1.21.1`, etc..

What would be the appropiate to document these tools' versions in a Git repository? So that anyone interested in replicating that project should be with the appropriate versions of the tools it depends on?

Comment: Without knowing what build tools you plan to support, I would say just document your requirements in the README file (which should explain how to build and run your code anyway).

Comment: If my project had many dependencies (say, 20+), wouldn't be quite a burden to look for the version used in the 20 dependencies and also wouldn't look ugly in the README having so much of the versions?

Comment: Python requirements (like `numpy`) should be recorded in your `requirements.txt` file. Most other languages have a standard for specifying dependencies as well. If you have real dependencies beyond language-specific modules, document those  in your README. If you have more than one or two, either you're over-specifying things or you have a real outlier.

Comment: Python was an example. About any other language, like Rust, Elixir, zsh, etc. Would I use a similar approach to Python's `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: Rust uses `cargo.toml` configuration files to record dependencies. Go (since 1.13 or so) uses `go.mod`. Elixir uses a `mix.exs` file. zsh does not have anything built in, as far as I know, but since it's a shell, it's easy to write your own.

Comment: Most languages have their own build tools. (If you are building anything substantial in `zsh`, you're doing something wrong.) Things like Nix and Docker provide ways to combine requirements in a language-agnostic way.

Comment: Ok, that's the questions I was looking for. Languages have their own tools and Docker is the language-agnostic way. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can make requirement.txt file where you can write all libraries with versions e.g.

```
numpy == 1.21.1
...
```

and then add this file to git repo. Someone can get all this packages with `pip install -r requirements.txt`